# Imre Ruzsa Generalisation of Kneser's theorem proof

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, reference-request, combinatorial-group-theory, additive-combinatorics

According to this post [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133408/karolyis-theorem-for-finite-groups-and-its-extensions), there is a theorem by Ruzsa (2009) that for any group $G$ and $A,B\subset G$, $|A+B| \ge \min\{ p(G), |A|+|B|-1\}$ where $p(G)$ is the size of the smallest subgroup of $G$.

I cannot find this anywhere on the internet. I've read his notes from conferences since 2009 about sum sets and there is nothing about this. Could someone help me find the proof?

Comment: Theorem 1.6 in DeVos's [arxiv:1301.0096](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.0096.pdf) cites this result from J.H.B. Kemperman, On complexes in a semigroup, Indag. Math. 18 (1956), 247-254.

Comment: A proof due to DeVos is found here http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/q7/q7.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in the field but it seems like you are looking for the Cauchy-Davenport theorem generalization for an arbitrary group $G$. [Here](https://cds.cern.ch/record/904813/files/cer-002575022.pdf) you can find the theorem for arbitrary *finite* groups.

Comment: I am aware, however Ruzsa has proven this for ALL groups